# What's a template file? Why I can't write php code into it?

Tags: templates, smarty

Questions in the title... I know there are different template engines like smarty...

I downloaded a script and want to modify the template files with php code. But I can't figure out what temple engine is used and adding php code doesn't work. So who can explain me how these template files work more detailed?

Answer (score 0):

Smarty is a template engine. The role of template engine is separating logic / model / controller from displaying data (view). There are many template engines and almost all have their own syntax.

So Smarty as other template engine should work like this - you make any calculations, decisions and data manipulation (for example getting data from database, choosing page to display), you pass data to Smarty (using assign method) and in Smarty you simple display data.

In fact in theory you can write php code into Smarty templates but it's a very bad practice and in the newest versions of Smarty you need to use backward compatibility class to do it. In fact almost in all applications there won't be any reason to use php in template file.